# Retrieving double value from MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

I.m storing the value **123456789.00** in an SQL column of `float` type, but when I'm retrieving it, the result set gives returns **1.23456789E8**. I want it to retrieved the value exactly like stored, i.e. **123456789.00**.

Comment: Please name the DB that you use, and also provide the related source code.

Comment: @VadimLanda , **What is mysql then  ??**

Comment: Why float, and not decimal?

Comment: Value stores correctly in db column. this problem occurs only when im retrieving value from db.   
i use vRMStdCost = rs.getDouble(10); and asigns txt_StandardCost.setText(""+obj_rmstock_tableclass.vRMStdCost); to textbox as a string. but value is in the form of1.23456789E8

Answer (score 2):

If you want store floating point value with precision than mysql column type should be `DECIMAL(size, precision)`. Here maximum size is 64. So, use `DECIMAL` instead of `float`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always store it as `VARCHAR` and when you retrieve it, convert it into double.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think 123456789.00 is too big number to store into a MySQL `float` type. You need to reformat when you retrieve the value, or change the type (to a `double` or `varchar`, for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query for retrieving value

`SELECT FORMAT(Column_Name,2) FROM TableName`